# How do i make the textboxes expand to fill the remaining space of the Grid Cell?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following window with some input `textboxes`. But these textboxes will not expand to fill the remaining space of the second column. Furthermore when the window resizes the `textboxes` doesn't **resize** accordingly,

Here is my window

[image]

Here is my XAML markup

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="28"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="First Name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
        <Label Content="Last Name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
        <Label Content="Street Name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"></Label>
        <Label Content="Suburb" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"></Label>
        <Label Content="City" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"></Label>

        <TextBox Width="313" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBox Width="313" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="313" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="3" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="313" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="3" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="313" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="3"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content="Save" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Width="100" Margin="3" />
        <Button Content="Exit" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Width="100" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="3"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <!--<TextBox Width="313" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

1. Is there away to expand the `textboxes` to fill the remaining space in the second column?
2. Is there away to make the `textboxes` resize with the form resize?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have the Width hardcoded, so it is always going to stay the same. Remove it, and change the alignment to stretch

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

Comment: Instead of removing Width, I'd recommend changing it to `MinWidth="313"`.  That way you get the stretch behavior but also avoid the possibility of the user resizing into an unusable situation.

Comment: @Chris Developer is not responsible for user's unwise usages!

Answer (score 5):

Just a note, if somebody facing with the same problem:

For me the problem was that I use the SharedSizeGroup on the grid for both of my 2 columns.
If i deleted the sharedsizegroup="b" on the columns what is *, the problem solved.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
            Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                        <Grid Margin="0 10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="a" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  **SharedSizeGroup="b"**/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="Size (m): " />
                            <TextBox x:Name="RealObjSize"
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     MinWidth="50"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                     TextChanged="RealObjSize_OnTextChanged" />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid Margin="0 10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="a" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" **SharedSizeGroup="b"**/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="Distance (m): " />
                            <TextBox x:Name="RealObjDist"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 MinWidth="50"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 TextChanged="RealObjDist_OnTextChanged" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I did something similar, but bound the width of one of the textboxes to the other.

Answer (score 0):

just put HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  and remove the  Width